# errors after adding AdMob in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, admob

After I integrated the AdMob SDK, I kept getting this error when trying to build it on a real device. The weird thing is, when it is built on the iOS simulator, everything works correctly.

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error

ld: framework not found Metal for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using xCode 5.1 and testing on an iPhone 5S running on iOS 7. Please help!

Comment: Metal is only available since iOS 8. You can't use it with a Base SDK of iOS 7.

Comment: @rmaddy does this mean I can't integrate adMob? how do I take out Metal?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Ramis yes this was back when I was using an older version of xCode and this issue went away after I updated to the newer xCode version that was out at the time

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this, is actually a bug / bad design by Apple, which failed to preserve backward compatibility for non-Metal devices..

[See here for more info](https://www.appsee.com/blog/dev/xcode-new-link-frameworks-automatically-fix-framework-not-found-metal-for-architecture-armv7). :)

Comment: I took a look at that and set “Link Frameworks Automatically” to NO. The same problem still occurs. I even tried removing all the frameworks I had for AdMob and then re-adding them, it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?